# Как передать переменную из JS скрипта в шаблон Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

мой шаблон Django создает таблицу из модели:
'''

```
<tbody>
 {% for status in device_statuses  %}
   <tr>
     <td>
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-content={{status.status}}></i></a>
     </td>
     <td> {{ status }} </td>
     <td> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times btn-outline btn-danger"></i></a> </td>
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}         
</tbody>
```

'''

При нажатии на  у меня открывается модальное окно вот таким кодом:

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="content"></p> 
      </div>           
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

На просторах интернета я нашел, как передать значение из JS текстом:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            // получить кнопку, которая его открыло
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            // извлечь информацию из атрибута data-content
            var content = button.data('content')
            // вывести эту информацию в элемент, имеющий id="content"
            $(this).find('#content').text(content);
        });
```

Но никак не могу найти инфу, как мне передать из кода JS переменную, которую я могу использовать в форме? ну, например, передать {{status.id}} во всплывающее окно, чтобы там я мог сделать там форму и, к примеру, передать этот {{status.id}} во View.

заранее спасибо!

Comment: Отправить http-запрос с нужной информацией на Django-сервер, и в Django его обработать как нужно

Comment: так у меня как раз проблема в том, чтобы понять, как выцепить нужную информацию. Запрос то я сделаю, но как мне во всплывающем окне переменную этого запроса получить? мне нужен  {{status.id}}, а я с помощью своего джава скрипта могу только подставить в <p>